# overwriten save method in django models doesn't work

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model that has an ImageField and I want to name it to its id that generated by AutoField, and therefore I overwrite the `save()` method in my model. But when I create an instance of the model in Admin panel, the picture name is set to `None.png`.

How can I fix that?

My `models.py` is:

```
from django.db import models
import os

def get_image_name(instance, filename):
    fn = os.path.join('img/thumbnailCategory/', str(instance.id) + '.png')
    return fn


class Category(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)
    c_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_name, null=False, blank=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.title
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand why you've defined save here at all. You haven't done anything specific with it. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Id is created after model save

Comment: There is also no need of specifying `id` as `AutoField`. `AutoField` should be specified if you need to modifiy the default behaviour of Django.

Comment: As @Ykh said, the id is generated only after the model has been saved. Therefore you'll always have `None.png`. You could use `uuid.uuid4` to generate a random UUID. That would be IMO a better approach.

Comment: You overwrite the `save`, but you do not do anything in the `save` function.

Comment: You can't save the filename as the instance's id because the object has not been saved yet. See below from 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

"In most cases, this object will not have been saved to the database yet, so if it uses the default AutoField, it might not yet have a value for its primary key field."

Comment: @DanielRoseman how can use save() method? how can I use its own object id in the picture name?

Comment: @Ykh : is there any way to parallely generate id and use it in the name of picture?

Comment: Yes,use post_save signal to modify picture name to id and restore changed name to instance.